# customising JAXB generation to include @XmlElementDecl annotation for ObjectFactory classes

Tags: java, binding, jaxb, code-generation

As in the subject, can you customise how xjc generates java classes so that each ObjectFactory class is annotated with @XmlElementDecl or each element with @XmlRootElement? Is there a way to do so with bindigns.xml file or some kind of command-line switch? I am using cxf maven plugin (so basically wsdl2java)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that @XmlElementDecl or @XmlRootElement are generated only for globally defined elements in XSD. The rules when which of the annotation is used are very well described in the following [blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html)